# Google Sheets - Percentage Calculation

Tags: google-sheets

Would do this manually but it would be best done auto.

Column A is product name.

Column B is Product Price.

Column C should be Column B entry plus a percentage (in this case VAT which is currently 21%

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Please include some information about what you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I spent over an hour looking at other queries but the requirements and responses in other people's cases were too far removed from what I'm trying to do in this case unfortunately.

Comment: If `B2` has price in it then in `C2` you can write `=B2*(1.21)` to make it 21% higher than B2.

Comment: In B3 I have a four figure sum. So in C3 it came out like 624287.00% ... which is obviously no good because column C should be a currency denomination i.e. another four figure sum. This is starting to make me think that it would be quicker just to work out the percentages myself and enter them in the relevant row of column C. Ideally I was hoping that when a figure was entered into each row of column B, Column C would automatically display Row X Column B plus 21%.

Comment: If I divide 624287 by 1.21 I don't get a 4-digit number. Your equation might have a mistake. Once  you have the correct equation in cell C2, hover your mouse on the bottom right and you will see a small square. Drag it down to the rows below to copy the from C2 to rows below it.

Comment: Thanks. OK here's an actual example. In B5 I have 2993, with your method C5 looks like 362153.00%... What it should say is 3621.53.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/vZcVO) is a screenshot of the formula that I enter and [this](https://imgur.com/a/KWJei) is what I get. Are you typing `121` instead of `1.21`?

Comment: Nah I literally copied and pasted what you typed. However, I've just entered a new column and tried again and this time it's working, so not sure what was happening. Will delete the old column. It doesn't seem to be absolutely accurate e.g. If I have 2992.50, it's resulting 3621 in Column C. However, if I work the sum out myself the answer should be 2992.50 + 628.43 (which is 21% of 2992.50) = 3620.93. Not sure I can get away with that discrepancy. Thanks for your help though Amit.

Comment: You had the format for the old column set to `Percent`. For your current issue, you can select the Column C, click 'Format' in the tool bar and then from the 'Number' option choose how many decimal places you want to show.

Comment: You're clever you. I did indeed have it set to percent, I remember doing that with my trial and error stuff in the very beginning. You've also fixed the discrepancy. Good man.

Answer (score 0):

> If B2 has price in it then in C2 you can write =B2*(1.21) to make it
>   21% higher than B2.

– Amit Singh